# Enviar mail con imagen adjunta desde formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios, imagen, mail

La situación es la siguiente: he logrado que se envíe un mail a través de un formulario con PHP y todos los datos se envían correctamente, excepto las imágenes. Tengo un input type file para que el usuario pueda escoger una imagen y que esta se envie en el mail, pero lo que ocurre es que en el mail aparece el nombre del archivo (ej: imagen.jpg) en vez de la imagen. No sé como puedo solucionar esto, dejo a continuación el código:

**Formulario:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-register" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="form-register__body">
        <div class="step3">                
            <div class="step__body">

              <label for="name">Nombre</label>
              <input required type="text" name="name" id="name">

              <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
              <input required type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input required type="email" name="email" id="email">

              <label for="customFileLang">Imagen: (opcional)</label>
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="imagen" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="es">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleccionar imagen</label>
              </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
include('correo.php'); ?>
</div>
```

**Correo.php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['apellido']) && !empty($_POST['email'])  ){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
$asunto = "Datos usuario";
$repEmail= "ejemplo@ejemplo.com";
$header = "From:noreply@example.com" . "\r\n";
$header.= "Reply-To:noreply@example.com" . "\r\n";
$header.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$header.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
$msg = "

<h3>DATOS PERSONALES</h3>
<b>Nombre:</b> $name <br>

<b>Apellido:</b> $apellido <br>      
<b>Email:</b> $email <br> <br>
<b>Imagen:</b> $imagen <br> <br>
";
$elMail = mail($repEmail, $asunto, $msg, $header);
if($elMail){
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Enviado")';
echo '</script>';
}else {
echo "<h4> NO SE PUDO ENVIAR </H4>";
}
}else {
echo "<h5> Error al enviar </h5>";
}
}?>
```

Comment: Hola. Estás tratando de recoger la imagen en `$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];` **No se encuentra allí** los archivos recogidos en el cliente son llevados al servidor en **$_FILES** y guardados en el **directorio temporal** debes recogerlo desde ese array y moverlo antes de enviarlo porque al servir la respuesta el colector de basura del sistema borra lo que esté en tmp y no se enviarán aunque las referencias sean válidas.

Comment: Para incluir el archivo como "adjunto" debes usar otro tipo de contenido (`Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="xxxxxxx"`) y generar el contenido usando 'boundaries'. Revisa https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#125168